# Java EE 6 form-authentication and FacesContext.isUserInRole

Tags: java-ee-6, facelets, form-authentication

I'm using a form-based authentication (with a JDBC-realm) to authenticate users in my EE application. I created a `/home/*` section, which is only accessible if a user is in the role USER or ADMIN.

Everything is working fine, but the problem is that when I use the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().isUserInRole(role)`-Method (for example to decide whether some UI-components are shown on the gui or not), the return value always is false.

I have absolutely no idea why the method always returns false. What am I missing?

The most confusing thing is, that I have implemented the exact same behaviour in another project (on the same glassfish-server-instance) and it works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem: I forgot to add the `@DeclareRoles()` annotation.

You have to Declare the roles you want to use somewhere in your application. I for example use  a SingletonEJB in which I declare the roles I'm using (using the DeclareRoles-Annotation).

Example:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@DeclareRoles({ "ADMIN", "USER" })
public class Application {
}
```

Comment: If you could add a little bit more information (where is that annotation needed, for example), then others with the same problem will have an easier time solving it.